# How to give root permission for Catlog on Android

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I was trying to capture logs on my unrooted phone using [Catlog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en). But I couldn't get the logs from the app that I am debugging because because Catlog don't have root permission. Is there any way to enable this permission?

Comment: Is 'Catlog' an application? You need to root your phone to use applications that require root

Comment: No, you cannot. Stock Android has no concept of "root permission" nor mechanism for running 3rd party code as root on production devices.  However, the ADB connection does run code with sufficient permission to read logs over that, which is how you are supposed to accomplish log debugging.

Comment: @DerGolem the question is on how to give permission which can't be done in the manifest because of security issues.

Comment: @Pris Yes is an app which can basically recored optionally save or send you logs. you can also filter this logs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton check out this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/dEsqi0dyPkkJ)

Comment: what is your original problem? why do you need to read device logs?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar I wanted to record the device log regardless of the device default log size and I like the option to send the log easily via mail.

Comment: @Arade.. Still unsure about why do you need all that logs.. staring from Jelly bean android does not allow apps to read logs data of other apps.. but each app can read its own log data.. Catlog has now open source their code so you can integrate the log reading code in your app.. check out this blog from catlog for more detail http://nolanlawson.com/2012/09/02/catlog-jives-with-jelly-bean-goes-open-source/

Comment: And if you are looking to track crashes you can use something like http://www.crittercism.com/ or https://github.com/ACRA/acra ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can give the permission from ADB, The ADB command to grant an application permission to read the logs is:

```
adb shell pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

We this permission will be persisted as long as you uninstall and install back the app.

Comment: adb shell pm grant com.nolanlawson.logcat android.permission.READ_LOGS